# How to get video quality control in HTML 5 player

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, video-streaming, html5-video

I am using this HTML 5 player:
https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

All the configurations above are working fine.
I am working on an application that requires youtube videos to be shown in my app.

But I am not able to see quality control when using youtube videos.
Is it possible here?

Can somebody please help?

or

Can someone suggest some other way to use videos in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use html Iframe to display Youtube Videos.
Can select a video and get embeded link and add it to src of iframe we can choose the height,width and autoplay options

Comment: I tried using Iframe Player:
But since it doesn't allow individual controls to hide/show, I can't use it.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#:~:text=The%20IFrame%20player%20API%20lets%20you%20embed%20a,or%20retrieve%20information%20about%20the%20video%20being%20played.

Comment: hide and show can be manipulated by  Javascript functions

Comment: you can wrap it up in a div and hide the div when needed

Comment: Yes we can but controls are displayed inside youtube player, which is hosted on another domain "youtube.com". Therefore, due to CORS policy, I can't